# My Magento 2 is not working properly?

Tags: magento2, error

When we reload our product pages so product images not loading even detials not showing :(

[image]

```
Website: http://thekoonj.com/
```

Please review product page and also homepage product slider not working or page refresh.

I do not know why it is happaning...

Comment: Please Explain Question

Comment: i think problem with cache. please clear cache and check.

Comment: No cache is fine and working but i think their is some owner permission issue with some directories :(

Comment: Switch to [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode) if you haven't already and it should display errors in the browser. You can also try to [redeploy static view files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html).